# React - Change State with passed arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I setState with a passed prop to a function?

```
<button onClick={ () => this.handleClick(person2) }>

handleClick = (person) => {

   console.log(person);
   const value = this.state.person

   console.log(value) // this returns undefined.

   this.setState({ person: !value })
}
```

So I want to change the state of person2. State:

```
this.state = {
  person1: false,
  person2: false,
  person3: false
 }
```

`person` is the argument passed in `handleClick`. Based on the argument, I want to change the state. How do I do that?

Comment: Try: `this.setState({ [person]: 'Changed' })`

Comment: @Titus, I edited the question. Please check the function again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleClick = personNumber => {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
      [personNumber]: !prevState[personNumber]
   }))
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to change the value to true/false. I edited the question. Please check. I'm getting undefined for the `value`

Comment: Why the ``...prevState`` ?

Comment: oh yeah, my bad @rohit